# Where are SITEFINITY created Pages stored

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sitefinity

I`m using Sitefinity CMS and I created a couple pages which different content. I am having trouble to find out where this page. Is there something particular which I am missing. I want to see the phisycal files of the created pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a physical file created. all page information is stored in the database.